# Segmentation fault in pthread_cond_signal()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

First let me provide some background. There are two threads in the production code and synchronization is done via wait and signal. Basic Structure of the code given below. main.c create the thread. main.c also calls funca() which signals the other thread. The mutex and condition variable is declared and initialized in a.c. a.c also has the definition of funca() and the definition of thread_func(). thread_func() waits for the condition and upon being signaled, unlocks the mutex and does some work.

## main.c

```
pthread_create(thread_id, thread_func)

funca();
```

## a.c

```
pthread_mutex_t     renotify_signal_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t      renotify_signal_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

thread_func() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&renotify_signal_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&renotify_signal_cond, &renotify_signal_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&renotify_signal_mutex);

        <<<<< Does some work here
}

funca() {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&renotify_signal_mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&renotify_signal_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&renotify_signal_mutex);

}
```

The segmentation fault is coming in pthread_cond_siganl(). Upon examining in gdb I could see that the mutex the condition variable binds to is corrupted i.e. the address should be that of signal_mutex but actually it is pointing to invalid memory. Please see gdb output below:

```
(gdb) x/40 0x85084a0
0x85084a0 <renotify_signal_mutex>:      0x00000001      0x00000000      0x00003b1a      0x00000000
0x85084b0 <renotify_signal_mutex+16>:   0x00000002      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x85084c0 <renotify_signal_cond>:       0x00000001      0x00000008      0x00000004      0x00000000
0x85084d0 <renotify_signal_cond+16>:    0x00000004      0x00000000      0x00000003      0x00000000
0x85084e0 <renotify_signal_cond+32>:    0x0200a084      0x00005008      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x85084f0 <_breakpoint_target_>:        0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x8508500 <bgp_asn_buffer>:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x8508510 <bgp_asn_buffer+16>:  0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x8508520 <bgp_asn_buffer+32>:  0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x8508530 <bgp_asn_buffer+48>:  0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
(gdb) p renotify_signal_cond
$51 = {
  __data = {
    __lock = 1,
    __futex = 8,
    __total_seq = 4,
    __wakeup_seq = 4,
    __woken_seq = 3,
    __mutex = 0x200a084,
    __nwaiters = 20488,
    __broadcast_seq = 0
  },
  __size = "\001\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\004\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\004\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\204\240\000\002\bP\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
  __align = 34359738369
}
gdb) x 0x200a084
0x200a084:      Cannot access memory at address 0x200a084
(gdb)


(gdb) p &renotify_signal_mutex
$53 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0x85084a0 <renotify_signal_mutex>
```

As you can see in the gdb output that the mutex field in pthread_cond_t structure is pointing to invalid memory instead of pointing to renotify_signal_mutex. Also the __nwaiters = 20488 looks wrong.

From the memory dump I dont see any possibility of memory overwriting. I also don't see any possibility of using uninitialized mutex/condition which might have lead to this. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the internal working of `pthread_cond_t` but I wouldn't expect it to contain a pointer to your `pthread_mutex_t` - the mutex pointer inside the `pthread_cond_t` object is probably one the library keeps for its own internal uses.

Comment: @MichaelBurr. Even initially I thought that the mutex is for internal purposes of pthread condition. However when I printed other condition variables, I could see that every one of them is having the mutex that is used in pthread_mutex_lock() before the condition_signal call. My guess is that this binding happens when the other thread calls pthread_cond_wait() because the wait call takes the mutex as a parameter.

Comment: That's no way to treat a good function like `pthread_create`. Post the real code if you want an answer

Comment: Maybe a dup pf https://stackoverflow.com/a/23400417/4386427

Comment: Have you tried setting a watchpoint on a member of the condition  variable? It may point to the source of the corruption.

Comment: in your `x 0x200a084` the 0x20 and 0x0a could be a space character followed by a newline. This is a hint that your `<<<<< Does some work here` part of the code might have a buffer overflow somewhere, corrupting memory of the mutex.

Comment: @nos. I thought about this possibility but IMHO it is not what is happening in this case. renotify_signal_mutex and renotify_signal_cond are global variable. and upon examining the memory I dont see any other variable from the same process in the adjacent memory location i.e 0x8508490 and 0x8508500 are from different process. The variables used inside "<<<<< Does some work here" region, do not appear in adjacent location of 0x85084c0. Hence they can't corrupt the memory. Do you agree? Can you please let me know?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer. Thanks and I will try this. This happened only once and the code in question has been there for an year. I am still trying to reproduce the issue .

Comment: @4386427. I will try to better summarize the code with more detail and paste it here.

Comment: @NeilB By the way, what are your glibc and libgcc versions at run time? Your addresses look like 32-bit, and there was a libgcc bug which introduced a memory corruption issue into the i386 conditional variable implementation in glibc.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer. Yes process is 32bit though CPU is 64bit. glibc version is 2.15 and libgcc version is 4.6.3.

Comment: @NeilB Do you use thread cancellation (`pthread_cancel`)?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer. Yes I use it but only when process is getting killed or exiting gracefully. After you mentioned it, I checked the debug log from the system but dont see thread_cancel part of the code getting executed. Are you thinking that after doing thread_cancel(), code is trying reuse the stale thread?

Comment: @NeilB No, I just fondly remember a libgcc bug which caused memory corruption in `pthread_cond_wait` because it resulted in the wrong cancellation handler being invoked. It's one way to get memory corruption with condition variables without an application bug. I can add the details in an answer if you want, but I'm not sure if they are relevant to your bug if it hits without cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a simplification in your code example, but the pthread_create does not look correct.  The format for pthread_create is:

`int pthread_create(
                 pthread_t *thread,
                 const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                 void *(*start_routine)(void *),
                 void *arg);`

This will possible corrupt memory.  Also, thread_func, should be passed as &thread_func to pthread_create.

Comment: Yes,  it was a simplified code example. In actual code I use all arguments correctly.  pthread_create(&renotify_thread_id, NULL, renotify_thread, NULL);

Comment: @NeilB: maybe you need to post the actual code - perhaps with some details removed, but the structure should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for memory corruption.

- The memory corruption is happening because of any other variable. Possibly writing an array goes out of bound or writing to const string or something similar. Sometimes stack trace does not show exact point of corruption.
- It seems mutex binding is happening at the time of pthread_cond_wait(). There is another thread using the same condition variable with a different mutex. But here, mutex address cannot be accessed. So, the corrupt mutex is not a global variable.