# Problem with pthread_cond_wait on multi-core processors

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool, mutex

I'm writing a program which receive data from websocket and work with this data in thread pool.
I have problem with pthread_cond_wait when processor have 2 or more cores. After pthread_cond_signal signal is received by all threads which run on different cores. For example if I have 2 cores, then the signal will come to 2 threads at once, which are located on these two cores.  If I have single core processor all is good.
What I have to do to get the program to work correctly on multi-core processors? So that only one thread receives the signal to start work.
I wrote an example of my code with  generation random text data instead of websocket data.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_attr_t attrd;
pthread_mutex_t mutexQueue;
pthread_cond_t condQueue;

char textArr[128][24]; //array with random text to work
int tc; //tasks count
int gi; //global array index

void *workThread(void *args){
 int ai;//internal index for working array element 
 while(1){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexQueue);
  while(tc==0){
   pthread_cond_wait(&condQueue,&mutexQueue); //wait for signal if tasks count = 0.
  }
  ai=gi;
  if(gi==127)gi=0;else gi++;
  tc--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexQueue);
  printf("%s\r\n",textArr[ai]);
  // then work with websocket data
 }
}

void *generalThread(void *args){
 const char chrs[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; //chars fo random text generation
 int ai=0;
 srand(time(NULL));
 while(1){
  for(int i=0;i<23;i++)textArr[ai][i]=chrs[rand()%61];//generating data instead of websocket data 
  textArr[ai][23]='\0';
  tc++;
  pthread_cond_signal(&condQueue); //Send signal for thread to begin work with data
  if(ai==127)ai=0;else ai++;
 }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
 pthread_attr_init(&attrd);
 pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrd,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
 pthread_t gt,wt[32];
 for(int i=0;i<32;i++)pthread_create(&wt[i],&attrd,&workThread,NULL);
 pthread_create(&gt,NULL,&generalThread,NULL);
 pthread_join(gt,NULL);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `generalThread` has two problems. First, it should have the mutex locked when updating `tc` and calling `pthread_cond_signal`. Second, it should `sleep` for a bit when the circular buffer fills up. As the code is now, the `generalThread` could add strings to the buffer faster than the workers remove them.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks. But if I check tc!=0 both of threads will return true because they work equally. <-- It was answer on the first version of your comment

Comment: @user3386109 when websocket working the buffer fills up rather slowly. No need in sleep. How mutex lock in generalThread will help receive signal at once?

Comment: @ BadMan After writing my now-deleted comment, I noticed that you *are* checking `tc!=0`, because of the `while (tc==0)` loop. So the code is already written to handle spurious wakeup. And if two threads wake up, only one should be able to acquire the mutex. So only one thread should see `tc!=0`. You can verify this by calling `sleep` in the `generalThread` after every call to `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: Another thing that seems to missing in the code is [initialization of the mutex and condition variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400097).

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, I tested this code with sleep after signal on a dual-core processor. The output comes only 1 time.
It is not clear why in my version with a websocket there is an access to the array from two threads at once and it works with a cell that has not been filled yet.

Comment: That may be a race condition in the code that writes to the buffer in the websocket version. You need to have that mutex locked when adding to the queue.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks. I will try to lock in generalThread soon and will write the result here

Comment: @user3386109 yep, only adding mutex lock to tc++ in generalThread make program work correctly

Comment: That's great news! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

First some info:

**man** [pthread_cond_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait)

> **Rationale**
>
> Some implementations, particularly on a multi-processor, may sometimes cause multiple threads to wake up when the condition variable is signaled simultaneously on different processors.

**man** [pthread_cond_signal](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)

> **Rationale**
>
> **Multiple Awakenings by Condition Signal**
>
> On a multi-processor, it may be impossible for an implementation of pthread_cond_signal() to avoid the unblocking of more than one thread blocked on a condition variable.
>
> ...
>
> The effect is that more than one thread can return from its call to pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() as a result of one call to pthread_cond_signal(). This effect is called "spurious wakeup". Note that the situation is self-correcting in that the number of threads that are so awakened is finite; for example, the next thread to call pthread_cond_wait() after the sequence of events above blocks.

So far, so good, the code in your `workThread` is proper synchronized (but you should put the `printf` in the synchronized section as well) but the code in your `generalThread` has no synchronization at all. Encapsulate the code in the while loop with a lock / unlock.

In that case, the first awakened thread has to aquire a lock on the specified mutex, which will be owned by either another thread or the `generalThread`. Until the mutex is unlocked, the thread blocks (no matter the reason of its wakeup). After the aquisition, it owns the mutex and all other threads will be blocked, the `generalThread` inclusive.

**Note**: a `pthread_cond_wait` implicitly unlocks the specified mutex upon entering the wait state and on a wakeup it tries to aquire a lock on the specified mutex.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand I have to lock tc++; in generalThread

Comment: Everything which is accessed and modified by each thread.

Comment: It seems, that `gi` is the only save variable (appears only in `workThread`).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a mutex lock to `tc++` fully corrects my programs:

```
void *generalThread(void *args) {
   const char chrs[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   int ai=0;
   srand(time(NULL));
   while(1){
      for(int i=0;i<23;i++)textArr[ai][i]=chrs[rand()%61];
      textArr[ai][23]='\0';
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexQueue); //this has been added 
      tc++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexQueue); //this has been added 
      pthread_cond_signal(&condQueue);
      if(ai==127)ai=0;else ai++;
   }
}
```